# How to properly create a table with foriegn key in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have created a table as below in shell:

```
create table Employees (Emp_ID int not null primary key, Emp_Name varchar(20), Hours_Logged int);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.11 sec)
mysql-sql> insert into Employees (Emp_ID,Emp_Name,Hours_Logged) values 
(123,'***',9);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)
mysql-sql> insert into Employees (Emp_ID,Emp_Name,Hours_Logged) values 
(456,'***',8);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)
mysql-sql> insert into Employees (Emp_ID,Emp_Name,Hours_Logged) values 
(789,'**',10);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.02 sec)
mysql-sql> insert into Employees (Emp_ID,Emp_Name,Hours_Logged) values 
(345,'***',10);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.02 sec)
```

and then I tried to create a foreign key

```
mysql-sql> create table Project (
    Project_ID int not null primary key, 
    Project_Name varchar(20), 
    Project_Manager varchar(20), 
    CostPerHour int, 
    Minimum_LoggedinHours int,
    foreign key(Minimum_LoggedinHours) references Employees(Hours_Logged)
);
```

and ended up with the below error.

```
ERROR: 1215 (HY000): Cannot add foreign key constraint
```

Could anyone help me with what would be the correct one?

Comment: FK must reference a unique field. If Multiple employee have 2 hours you don't know which one is reference to

Comment: Post the tables and data as text [READ THIS](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Since it makes no sense, what you are trying to do, no-one can help you, until you explain what you actually want to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A foreign key must reference a unique field, what you could do it this

```
foreign key(Minimum_LoggedinHours) references Employees(Emp_ID)
```

And your shell command should work!

Comment: You dont need reference a PK. just one field with unique constraint